# echo value of input text box

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
    echo htmlentities($img_width);
    // Outputs: <input type="text" name="image_w" value="500" size="6" maxlength="5"/>
?>
```

I don't have access to 'image_w'.

How can I echo only the value (i.e.: 500)?

Comment: elaborate your question

Comment: $img_width is input box, I wish to use its ‘value’ for other variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<input required  type = "text" name = "image_w" value="' . $img_width. '" />'
```

try it

Comment: I’m looking for ‘value’ by using htmlentities.

Comment: you want to know image width is it?

Comment: yes, but the only way i can get it, is through the above echo. i don't have access to the input elements.